# Which version of The Oregon Trail is this?

Tags: version-differences, game-identification, the-oregon-trail

When my family got our first computer (in 1997) we got a copy of The Oregon Trail and became something of a family meme. Now, I'm trying to find out which version we had. The list below from Wikipedia shows these were (are) the different version, sans mobile and facebook:

- 1981 to 1985 The Oregon Trail (Apple II)
- 1992 The Oregon Trail Deluxe (MS-DOS).
- 1993-96 The Oregon Trail Ver 1.2 (Windows).
- 1996 The Oregon Trail II (Windows).
- 1997 The Oregon Trail 3rd Edition (Windows).
- 2001 The Oregon Trail 4th Edition (Windows).
- The Oregon Trail 5th Edition (Windows).

This is an image of the start menu as I remember it:

[image: screenshot of the main menu]

And [this](http://static.tombullock.co.uk/audio/Oregon_Trail_Theme.mp3) is the theme tune (not sure if it was different depending on version).

Comment: I know it's been answered already, but I was just going to say the graphics are waaaaaay too good for the old Apple II version. (I played that one a lot.)

Comment: This is the version with recorded dialog and updated sound effects.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You were playing **The Oregon Trail Deluxe (the 1992 MS-DOS) version**.

Answer (score 16):

This is the 1992 MS-DOS version.

Here's another screenshot of the game:

[image: The Oregon Trail]

You can find more info [here](http://www.thehouseofgames.net/index.php?t=10&id=391).

Answer (score 3):

This is actually Ver. 1.2

http://www.twitch.tv/monotonetim plays it all the time.  The older version the other comments refer to has a slightly different menu.